# Word for "fear of being discovered"

Tags: single-word-requests, emotions

What is a word that means "fear of being discovered"?
Preferably a word but a phrase will also do just fine.
In my case I want to use it like:

> He had constant fear that he would be discovered as the murderer
>   He had ___ that he was going to be discovered as the murderer

Comment: Josh, it might be more helpful if you put a _____ in for the word you want. Here I'm not sure if you want to replace "fear" or "discovered" or "fear that he would be discovered".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say '***exposure fear***'.

According to Merriam-Webster's Dictionary https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/exposure:

***EXPOSURE***

disclosure of something secret

// tried to prevent exposure of their past

Comment: "Fear of being exposed" would be my preference.

Comment: An unidiomatic phrase.

Comment: If I encountered *exposure fear* in the wild I wouldn't immediately know whether it meant *fear of being exposed* or *fear of exposing oneself* or even *fear of encountering someone exposing themselves*.

Answer (score -3):

There's a one-word psychological term (as a synonym to [impostor syndrome](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impostor_syndrome)), called **[impostorism](https://www.yourdictionary.com/impostorism)**; it is also known as impostor phenomenon, fraud syndrome or the impostor experience. According to Wikipedia, it is:

> a psychological pattern in which an individual doubts their accomplishments and has a persistent internalized **fear of being exposed as a "fraud"**.

or rather

> the feeling of being an impostor.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all. The imposter syndrome can be experienced by people who have done nothing criminal. *"doubts their accomplishments"* isn't the same as "fears their crime/guilt will be exposed".